# History of Fatou's Lemma

Tags: mathematics

This question concerns Fatou's Lemma:

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions on a measure space $X$. Define $f: X\to [0,+\infty]$ by $f(x) :=\liminf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$, for every $x\in X$. Then $f$ is measurable and $\int_X f\,d\mu \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n\,d\mu$.

This result is, of course, very famous now, but I'm having a hard time tracing back its genesis. After his thesis on integration theory, Fatou has worked in several areas, including complex analysis and iterated functions; so a natural guess would be that this Lemma originates from his PhD thesis, but I couldn't find any precise quote. In fact, it seems that the first occurrence of the name "Fatou's Lemma" (par excellence) can be found in a 1932 [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1989506?casa_token=fNtkJZBACXwAAAAA%3AEwhNAltGxG1lVK8jfipAjBgOhyvKiDLm6QTlx9D24w7Lu5_7gOAIG8gOJPVkH-LCIHq6n_OwMXi9WS-FeCoN_6VMb_pOpvDIkLgrrURISxeBxwoDtTo&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) by Doob, although I'm not completely sure Doob was referring to precisely what today goes under the same name.

Does anyone have closer information?

Comment: See pp. 375-376 of [*Séries trigonométriques et séries de Taylor*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485887163), **Acta Mathematica** 30 (1906), 335-400 and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22S%C3%A9ries+trigonom%C3%A9triques+et+s%C3%A9ries+de+Taylor%22+%22Fatou%27s+lemma%22&filter=0).

Comment: An interesting question to ask students when they learn Fatou's lemma:  "What was it a lemma for?"  You can also do that with Zorn's lemma.  Or other standard results well-kown as "lemmas".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Fatou formulated the lemma the modern way that Doob refers to. It appears in Fatou's paper [*Series trigonometriques et series de Taylor*, p. 375](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887163) (Acta Math., 30 (1906) 335-400), which he presented as his doctoral thesis. It was a side result in proving that if $f$ is bounded and analytic for $|z|<1$, then $\lim_{r\nearrow1} f(re^{it})$ exists almost everywhere. This, in turn, was part of his proof of a general form of Parseval's identity for trigonometric series of summable functions. Fatou's research was personally encouraged and aided by Lebesgue himself.

The details are described in [Lebesgue's Theory of Integration: Its Origins and Development by Hawkins, pp. 168-172](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/lebesgues-theory-of-integration-its-origins-and-development). Theorem 6.6 in the quote below is what we now call the Fatou's lemma:

> "*Theorem 6.6 is similar to the theorem of Beppo Levi referred to in
> 5.3. Fatou proved his theorem as follows: Let $L$ denote a positive number, and consider the set $E$ of all $x$ such that $f(x) < L$. A sequence of functions $g_n$ is constructed by setting $g_n(x) = f_n(x)$ if $f_n(x) <L$ and
> $g_n(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. Then for $x$ in $E$, $0<g_n(x)<L$, and $g_n(x)$ converges
> to $f(x)$. Lebesgue's Theorem 5.3 applies and shows that $\int_E f=
> \lim \int_E g_n <\liminf \int_a^b f_n$. The lemma then follows, since the right-hand side of the inequality is independent of $L$."*

The theorem 5.3 referred to is Lebesgue's extension of
the theorems of Arzela and Osgood to convergence of bounded measurable functions. The theorem of Levi was that if $f_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence of summable functions such that $\lim \int f_n$ is finite, then $f(x) = \lim f_n (x)$ is finite almost everywhere and summable with $\int f_n= \lim \int f_n$. It was published by Levi the same year in *Sopra l'integrazione delle serie* (Milano Ist. Lomb.
Rend., (2) 39 (1906) 775-80) and used by Fubini to prove his theorem on exchanging the order of integration. Here is some broader context from Hawkins:

> "*Parseval's equality for any summable function, bounded or not, was
> obtained shortly thereafter by Pierre Fatou (1878-1929). As his doctoral
> thesis Fatou [1906] presented a paper on "*Series trigonometriques
> et series de Taylor*" with the principal aim "to show the advantage that
> can be obtained in these questions from the new notions of the measure
> of sets and the generalized definite integral" [1906: 335]. He was particularly
> encouraged in this undertaking by his "friend H. Lebesgue
> who has not ceased to interest himself with my researches and whose
> advice has been very useful to me" [1906: 338].*"

Comment: Thanks! Very nice and complete answer.